# How can I get gallery images in a list view?

Tags: magento

I just want to get the "more views" area of the product view in my list view. 
Tried it with `getMediaGalleryImages` and `getGalleryImages`but it doesn't work.

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

    <!-- MORE VIEWS -->
        <p><?php echo $_product->getMediaGalleryImages() ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or is there a way to just load all the product view's in the product list ? Then I don't need to design the list view and the product view. Because I have only 12 products in my shop and I present them with jQuery scrollable.

greets 
Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, someone else helped me in another forum.
This did the trick:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>

    <p><?php echo $_product->getMediaGalleryImages() ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: That is a huge performance killer. You should not be loading products on a template, inside a loop.